# Switch statement in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, switch-statement

In the following script I have two callback functions: getProjectKey() and getWorkflowSchemeName().

I've passing a variable 'workflowSchemeName' in the switch statement, although I can see in the debugger that the value is coming but the switch statement doesn't work and keeps running on the default case.

Following is the code.

```js
if (AJS.$("#issue-create-submit").val() == "Create" || AJS.$("#create-issue-submit").val() == "Create") {
  inputTag = AJS.$("#project")[0];
  projectId = inputTag.value;

  var projectKey;
  var workflowSchemeName;

  function getProjectKey(projectId, callback) {
    console.log("Project ID is (inside function): " + projectId);
    var restCall = AJS.params.baseURL + "/rest/api/2/project/" + projectId;

    AJS.$.get(restCall, function(response) {
      callback(response);
      console.log(" REST PROJECT KEY IS : " + response.key);
    })
  }

  function getWorkflowSchemeName(projectKey, callback) {
    var restCall = AJS.params.baseURL + "/rest/projectconfig/1/workflowscheme/" + projectKey;

    AJS.$.get(restCall, function(response) {
      callback(response);
      console.log(" REST WorkflowScheme Name is: " + response.name);
    })
  }

  if (projectId != null) {
    getProjectKey(projectId, function(response) {
      projectKey = response.key;
      console.log("*************** PROJECT KEY IS : " + projectKey);

      if (projectKey != null) {
        getWorkflowSchemeName(projectKey, function(resp) {
          workflowSchemeName = resp.name;

          // Getting the WorkflowSchemeName till here. CAN see it in the console. 

          console.log("*************** WORKFLOWSCHEME IS : " + workflowSchemeName); // Can see this. 

          if (workflowSchemeName != null) {
            switch (workflowSchemeName) {

              // FAILING HERE
              case "SW Work Flow Scheme":
                console.log("SOFTWARE New Content Inside condition ");
                AJS.$(".field-group").children('label[for=description]').append('<span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span>');
                AJS.$(".field-group").children('label[for=customfield_10105]').append('<span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span>');
                break;

              case "HW Workflow Scheme":
                console.log("HARDWARE New Content Inside condition ");
                AJS.$(".field-group").children('label[for=description]').append('<span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span>');
                break;


                // DEFAULT CASE ALWAYS RUNS. 

              default:
                console.log("A new workflow scheme is detected. Need to update the Scripts Plugin in Create Issue Screens");
            }
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }

  // Can't see these values here either. But separate Issue. 
  console.log("Project Key is ************** " + projectKey);
  console.log("WorkflowScheme Name is ******** " + workflowSchemeName);
}
```

Can anyone please help me out, what am I doing wrong here? 
Many Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you showing us the log of the value coming from your REST service?  It's very difficult to tell what's wrong when you don't show your inputs.  Might want to put those log statements before you call `callback`

Comment: @prasad why would that matter?

Comment: Your workflowSchemeName may contain extra space. Please check it out. there is nothing wrong in your switch case.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers.
I don't know what was the problem, I-rewrote it again, and its working now. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch statement is correct. The problem is the value of var workflowSchemeName is not what you are checking for in switch case(space and case matters). Check this.

```
    var workflowSchemeName = 'SW Work Flow Scheme';

    switch (workflowSchemeName) {

        // FAILING HERE
    case "SW Work Flow Scheme":
        console.log("SOFTWARE New Content Inside condition ");
        //AJS.$(".field-group").children('label[for=description]').append('<span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span>');
        //AJS.$(".field-group").children('label[for=customfield_10105]').append('<span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span>');
        break;

    case "HW Workflow Scheme":
        console.log("HARDWARE New Content Inside condition ");
        //AJS.$(".field-group").children('label[for=description]').append('<span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span>');
        break;

        // DEFAULT CASE ALWAYS RUNS.

    default:
        console.log("A new workflow scheme is detected. Need to update the Scripts Plugin in Create Issue Screens");
    }

    var workflowSchemeName = 'HW Workflow Scheme';

    switch (workflowSchemeName) {

        // FAILING HERE
    case "SW Work Flow Scheme":
        console.log("SOFTWARE New Content Inside condition ");
        //AJS.$(".field-group").children('label[for=description]').append('<span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span>');
        //AJS.$(".field-group").children('label[for=customfield_10105]').append('<span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span>');
        break;

    case "HW Workflow Scheme":
        console.log("HARDWARE New Content Inside condition ");
        //AJS.$(".field-group").children('label[for=description]').append('<span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span>');
        break;

        // DEFAULT CASE ALWAYS RUNS.

    default:
        console.log("A new workflow scheme is detected. Need to update the Scripts Plugin in Create Issue Screens");
    }
```

The output is:

```
"SOFTWARE New Content Inside condition "
"HARDWARE New Content Inside condition "
```